# Addresses with no memory allocated

Tags: operating-systems, memory-access, memory-allocation

I've read that a program can crash if it tries to access addresses with no memory allocated. But, how is it possible that an address has no memory allocated? When does it happen?

Comment: I suggest finding an operating systems textbook and reading about virtual memory and dynamic memory allocation, to get some relevant background.